# Deploying SLIM 3 to shared host

Tags: slim, shared-hosting

Although installation of SLIM 3 on my local machine is successful: slim is up and running using MAMP (http://localhost:8888/backend2/public/[my-name]) generates slim 3 main page with "hello Daniel" . deploying all slim 3 directories and navigating to the same url but starting with www.delikates.co.il/backend2/public..... ends up with 503 server error. 
why is that ? what directories should or should not be uploaded to the server, what about .htaccess , where should it be located and why, what lines of code should it contain? thanx in advance Daniel.

Comment: Look at your error logs.

Comment: it's a shared hosting. My friend owns the company that manages the hosting server. He sais it is impossible to display error log because it does not exist

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think that slim 3 and slim 2 should be overlooked by serious developers. I have solved restful ajax issues by building native php code.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, the shared hosting expects your `index.php` to be in the root folder or in a specially named folder like `web` or `htdocs`. It probably doesn't look in `public`.

The hosting provider's documentation should be able to tell you this.

Comment: i have a folder: public_html on the shared host, that contains index.php + .htaccess that has shared host rools and it still gives me 500 ...

Comment: Hello, Rob. Could you please help me or shed some light on a real complicated trouble I got with deploying a Slim3 App? I always get `access denied` :( [Here is my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51003864/1883256).